# sed usage not able to understand

Tags: unix, sed

I have come across unix sed command usage and not able to understand what it does. Could you please help me to understand the usage ? If possible please share some reference to understand such usages of sed command.

```
sed -i '/^export JAVA_HOME/ s:.*:export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default\nexport HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop\nexport HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop\n:' $HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh
```

Comment: Are you confused about `sed`, or what this does? I'm sure you could find plenty of documentation on GNU sed -- https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/

Comment: I am confused about the usage of sed in this example. What really it does ? if some one cal help to break down the logical path for this command

Comment: It's replacing some text within a file. It'd be easier to read if you broke apart the patterns within the string

Answer (score 3):

The command is simple, though it assumes GNU `sed` because of the way it uses the `-i` option; for macOS Sierra and related systems, you'd need to use `-i ''` in place of just `-i`.

Overall, it corresponds to:

```
sed -i '/Pattern/ s:.*:Replacement:' file
```

where:

- `-i` means overwrite each input file with its edited output without creating a backup copy.
- `/Pattern/` is `^export JAVA_HOME`; a line starting with the word `export` and then `JAVA_HOME` separated by a single space.
- `s:.*:Replacement:` is a substitute command, using `:` instead of the more conventional `/` (often `s/.*/Replacement/`) as the pattern delimiter.  This is done because the replacement text contains slashes.  The `.*` matches the whole line.  The rest of the material is written in place of the original `export JAVA_HOME` line.  The `\n` sequence expands to a newline, so it actually produces a number of lines in the output.
- `file` is `$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh`

Comment: Thanks you very much .. this explains a lot .

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this is a `sed` command invocation. The command is short for "Stream EDitor" and is quite useful for modifying files programaticallly. Your best bet is to read the man pages (`man sed`, but   I've broken down your particular command here for instructive purposes:

```
sed                                     # The command
-i                                      # Edit file in place (no backup)
'/^export JAVA_HOME/                    # For every line that begins with 'export JAVA_HOME'...
s:                                      # substitue...
.*:                                     # the entire line with...
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/java/default
export HADOOP_PREFIX=/usr/local/hadoop
export HADOOP_HOME=/usr/local/hadoop
:'                                      # End of command
$HADOOP_PREFIX/etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh # Run on the following file
```

Points of interest:

- Commands can be limited to a particular address range or scope. Here, the scope was a search.
- The substitue command can be delimited by almost any character (usually it is `/`, but in this case, `:`   was chosen to prevent escaping of the `/` in the filepaths
- The `sed` expression was enclosed in `'` to prevent shell expansion of variables. Although no expansions would have taken place in this scenario, it is fairly common to see the expression wrapped in `'` to eliminate the possibility.